# Identifying SOAP Method Prefix from XSD/WSDL

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a WSDL as below. I am trying to identify how to get the Prefix for SOAP Methods from this document, can someone please help.

Below is the Prefix Method generated through SOAP-UI, please note the bold part **Foo** in the method prefix, is there any way can identify the prefix to use from the WSDL or XSD ?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                  xmlns:cad="http://Foobarlog.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <**Foo**:getCADPullLogs>
     <request>
     </request>
  </**Foo**:getCADPullLogs>
```

**WSDL File As Below**

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://Foobarlog.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://Foobarlog.com/" name="FoobarLogReadWebService">
<script />
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://Foobarlog.com/" schemaLocation="http://10.X.X.X:9099/FoobarLogWebService/FoobarLogReadWebService?xsd=1" />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getFoobarPullLogs">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getFoobarPullLogs" />
</message>
<message name="getFoobarPullLogsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getFoobarPullLogsResponse" />
</message>
<message name="getFoobarPushLogs">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getFoobarPushLogs" />
</message>
<message name="getFoobarPushLogsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getFoobarPushLogsResponse" />
</message>
<message name="getFoobarTxnDetails">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getFoobarTxnDetails" />
</message>
<message name="getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="FoobarLogReadWebService">
    <operation name="getFoobarPullLogs">
        <input wsam:Action="http://Foobarlog.com/FoobarLogReadWebService/getFoobarPullLogsRequest" message="tns:getFoobarPullLogs" />
        <output wsam:Action="http://Foobarlog.com/FoobarLogReadWebService/getFoobarPullLogsResponse" message="tns:getFoobarPullLogsResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getFoobarPushLogs">
        <input wsam:Action="http://Foobarlog.com/FoobarLogReadWebService/getFoobarPushLogsRequest" message="tns:getFoobarPushLogs" />
        <output wsam:Action="http://Foobarlog.com/FoobarLogReadWebService/getFoobarPushLogsResponse" message="tns:getFoobarPushLogsResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="getFoobarTxnDetails">
        <input wsam:Action="http://Foobarlog.com/FoobarLogReadWebService/getFoobarTxnDetailsRequest" message="tns:getFoobarTxnDetails" />
        <output wsam:Action="http://Foobarlog.com/FoobarLogReadWebService/getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse" message="tns:getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="FoobarLogReadWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:FoobarLogReadWebService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
    <operation name="getFoobarPullLogs">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getFoobarPushLogs">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getFoobarTxnDetails">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="FoobarLogReadWebService">
    <port name="FoobarLogReadWebServicePort" binding="tns:FoobarLogReadWebServicePortBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://10.X.X.X:9099/FoobarLogWebService/FoobarLogReadWebService" />
    </port>
</service>
```

**XSD as Below**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://Fooabrlog.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://Fooabrlog.com/">
<script />
<xs:element name="getFoobarPullLogs" type="tns:getFoobarPullLogs" />
<xs:element name="getFoobarPullLogsResponse" type="tns:getFoobarPullLogsResponse" />
<xs:element name="getFoobarPushLogs" type="tns:getFoobarPushLogs" />
<xs:element name="getFoobarPushLogsResponse" type="tns:getFoobarPushLogsResponse" />
<xs:element name="getFoobarTxnDetails" type="tns:getFoobarTxnDetails" />
<xs:element name="getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse" type="tns:getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse" />
<xs:complexType name="getFoobarPushLogs">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="request" type="tns:FoobarPushRequestObject" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarPushRequestObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="endDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="requestType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="startDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getFoobarPushLogsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="tns:FoobarPushResponseBean" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarPushResponseBean">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FoobarLogsResponse" type="tns:FoobarPushRequestBean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="responseText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarPushRequestBean">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="destination" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="header" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="messageStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="originator" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="requestID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="submitDT" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="treatDT" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getFoobarTxnDetails">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="request" type="tns:FoobarTxnRequestObject" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarTxnRequestObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FoobarRequestID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="endDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="requestType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="startDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getFoobarTxnDetailsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="tns:FoobarTxnResponseBean" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarTxnResponseBean">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FoobarTxnResponse" type="tns:FoobarTxnRequestBean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="responseText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarTxnRequestBean">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="header" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="requestID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="submitDT" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="treatDT" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getFoobarPullLogs">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="request" type="tns:FoobarPullRequestObject" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarPullRequestObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="endDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="requestType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="startDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getFoobarPullLogsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="tns:FoobarPullResponseBean" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarPullResponseBean">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FoobarLogsResponse" type="tns:FoobarPullRequestBean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="responseText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="FoobarPullRequestBean">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="destination" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="originator" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="requestID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="serviceProfileID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="submitDt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any prefix you like as long as it's mapped to the right namespace URI, namely the `targetNamespace` of the XSD (`http://Fooabrlog.com/`).  In the example XML you've supplied you have `xmlns:cad="http://Foobarlog.com/"` (which I presume is supposed to be the same URI but typoed in the question), so `<cad:getCADPullLogs>` should work.